# Create an array in a column from rows with duplicate data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large data set (about 600,000 rows). I want to reduce the number of rows of data by creating an array in the last column when the first 4 columns are the same.

```
      make  year      model          engine            part
alfa romeo  1960  giulietta         1.3l l4             A
alfa romeo  1958  giulietta         1.3l l4             B
alfa romeo  1958  giulietta         1.3l l4             A
alfa romeo  1957  giulietta         1.3l l4             B
alfa romeo  1957  giulietta         1.3l l4             A
alfa romeo  1956  giulietta         1.3l l4             B
alfa romeo  1956  giulietta         1.3l l4             A
alfa romeo  1954  giulietta         1.3l l4             B
alfa romeo  1954  giulietta         1.3l l4             A
alfa romeo  1955  giulietta         1.3l l4             B
alfa romeo  1955  giulietta         1.3l l4             A
```

**Desired output:**

```
      make  year      model          engine            part
alfa romeo  1960  giulietta         1.3l l4            [A]
alfa romeo  1958  giulietta         1.3l l4            [A,B]
alfa romeo  1957  giulietta         1.3l l4            [A,B]
alfa romeo  1956  giulietta         1.3l l4            [A,B]
alfa romeo  1955  giulietta         1.3l l4            [A,B]
alfa romeo  1954  giulietta         1.3l l4            [A,B]
```

I was thinking I would be able to use `dataframe.groupby` to obtain my desired output, but I was unable to through multiple attempts. I kept receiving a form of the following output `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at xxx>`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group them together and make a list of their contents.

```
df.groupby(['make', 'year', 'model', 'engine']).agg(list).reset_index()


make    year    model   engine  part
0   alfa romeo  1954    giulietta   1.3l l4 [B, A]
1   alfa romeo  1955    giulietta   1.3l l4 [B, A]
2   alfa romeo  1956    giulietta   1.3l l4 [B, A]
3   alfa romeo  1957    giulietta   1.3l l4 [B, A]
4   alfa romeo  1958    giulietta   1.3l l4 [B, A]
5   alfa romeo  1960    giulietta   1.3l l4 [A]
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually does the job too, but I do need to keep an index here. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Include `.reset_index()` at the end

Comment: Ahh perfect, should've tried that before asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can group then make a list of parts.

```
df = df.groupby(['make', 'year', 'model', 'engine'])['part'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Sample output:

```
         make  year      model   engine part
0  alfa romeo  1957  giulietta  1.3l l4  B,A
1  alfa romeo  1958  giulietta  1.3l l4  B,A
2  alfa romeo  1960  giulietta  1.3l l4    A
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm getting the following error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'transform'`

Comment: @Stephen Try my edit

Comment: Yes, this works great and also removes the duplicate rows. Only change would be adding `'engine'` to the groupby. Thank you!